# How do I get tkinter to work outside of IDLE?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, command-line

When I run my python scripts inside IDLE then tkinter works fine, however as soon as i try to run my script directly through the python launcher or the command line, I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/maclaren/Documents/hellotkinter.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

Im coding on mac, please help. How do I get my programms to run outside of an IDE?

Comment: Likely you are using a specific python install in your IDE, and another one (system python?) to run your code.
Could you give more details on your IDE, and what's the result of `which python` command executed in a system terminal, or from your IDE's terminal?

Comment: You may be running Python 2.x, in which case the module is named `Tkinter`.

Comment: I am running python 3x and i am using IDLE, i tried using import tkinter and from tkinter import * as commands, both work in the IDLE but not when i run it through the launcher. I tried using the most simple software to get my code to work (tkinter and IDLE) but i really getting frustrated. I tried it out by coding a simple hello world first

Comment: `pip install tkinter`...

Comment: Collecting tkinter
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tkinter

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using using IDLE python 3. In the command line, python 2 is the default. You should either change the import from

```
import tkinter
```

to

```
import Tkinter
```

or you can use python 3 in the command line. This is the best option because some Tk widgets are only available in python 3. Instead of this:

```
cd /Users/maclaren/Documents
python hellotkinter.py
```

try:

```
cd /Users/maclaren/Documents
python3 hellotkinter.py
```

or

```
cd /Users/maclaren/Documents
py hellotkinter.py
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, if your program doesn't work outside your IDE, open your program in your command prompt or terminal, by writing `python myfile.py` (*myfile.py* is the file that you are trying to run).

It will show you any errors in your file that your IDE sometimes doesn't show.